# Perl search and replace in file error "Bareword found where operator expected"

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I want to do a simple search and replace on a file:

```
perl -pi -e "s/{{REPLACE_ME}}/$base64_string/g" myfile.txt
```

Contents of myfile.txt:

```
This is my amazing base64 string:

{{REPLACE_ME}}
```

If I run this command:

```
perl -pi -e "s/{{REPLACE_ME}}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" myfile.txt
```

It results in the following error [shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVts3.png)

What is causing the issue? Also I don't need to use this command, if there is some other Perl or bash command that will achieve this simple search and replace of a base64 string without causing any issues I'm down to use that instead...

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy and paste the actual messages **as text**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `perl` command should work with alternative regex delimiters:

```
perl -pi -e "s~{{REPLACE_ME}}~$base64_string~" myfile.txt
```

Problem is that your `base64` string contains `/` and you are using `/` as regex delimiter.

Comment: Also, perl might warn you about `Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex`. If that *really* bothers you, then you can change the command to `perl -pi -e "s~\{\{REPLACE_ME\}\}~$base64_string~" myfile.txt`

Comment: One could escape the `/` in the base64 string, but this solution is far simpler.

Comment: Thanks I will test this tomorrow and pick your answer if it works.